# How to run Flyway migrate before jOOQ code generation using Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, kotlin, jooq, flyway

I'm trying to use Flyway and jOOQ together with Spring Boot (`spring-boot-starter-jooq` and autoconfigured Flyway both handled by Spring)

My problem is that the jOOQ code generation runs before Flyway migrate, so jOOQ doesn't see the changes made by Flyway.

I tried setting `dependsOn` for the jOOQ generator task to `flywayMigrate` but as it turns out Flyway is run only on startup. The Flyway Gradle plugin is not applied, so I have no `flywayMigrate` task.

When I tried adding it to my gradle config following the official Flyway guide:

```
apply plugin: "org.flywaydb.flyway"

flyway {
    url = 'jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/myDb'
    user = 'myUsr'
    password = 'mySecretPwd'
    schemas = ['public']
}
```

I get an exception:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.flywaydb.core.internal.util.jdbc.DriverDataSource
```

What am I doing wrong? How do I set this up so they work together nicely?

Note that I have the PostgreSQL driver and Flyway Core as a dependency:

```
implementation "org.postgresql:postgresql:42.2.5"
implementation "org.flywaydb:flyway-core"
```

so it should work. This is probably a Gradle vs Flyway vs Spring issue, because Flyway works when I start up my Spring app.